# Supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to follow the steps [here](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/jwt-bearer/) for OAuth2 using JWT Bearer, I have included the appropriate files as stated in the [installation instructions](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/).

However, when I run the following PHP code:

```
$private_key = file_get_contents("/www/var/includes/keyfile.pem");
$client_id   = 'example_client_id';
$user_id     = 'example_user_id';
$grant_type  = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer';
$jwt = generateJWT($private_key, $client_id, $user_id, 'https://api.example.com');
```

... I receive the following errors:

```
openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key

Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to sign data.'
```

I have read that using 'file_get_contents' might not be the best way, have tried other methods without luck.  Seems odd that the documentation from the first link specifically says to use it though?

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem with your `keyfile.pem` file

Comment: From the example you've linked, they're using `generateJWT` with a private RSA key (from a public / private key pair). A `.pem` file is typically a certificate

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! Do you know of a way to use a .pem file with JWT?  .pem is a requirement for this API.

Comment: There's an example here ~ https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/

Answer (score -1):

1. Prepare the “private key id”:

```
   $fp = fopen("/path/to/file/privatekey.pem", "r");
       $privKey = fread($fp, 8192);
       fclose($fp); 
   $pKeyId = openssl_get_privatekey($privKey, 'optional_passphrase');
```

2. Use in the openssl_sign:

`openssl_sign($dataToSign, $signatureVar, $pKeyId);`

Credit: https://rupom.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/openssl_sign-supplied-key-param-cannot-be-coerced-into-a-private-key/